# Set default screen options for all users

Tags: wordpress, screen, meta-boxes

How can I set the default screen options for all users in wordpress. I am looking for control over all sections and each section might be different. Example Custom Post Types, Pages, etc.

Also, how can I set the default meta box locations for all users.

it would be great to be able to mirror the screen options and metabox locations of one user and clone it for everybody. Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Check out [Adminimize (hide modules for specific roles)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/) and [Level2Categories 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/level2categories-2/).

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong, but it only gives you options to hide screen options (the whole tab) from users. I'm looking to actually choose what items are checked off in the screen options.

Comment: There is default_hidden_meta_boxes filter in get_hidden_meta_boxes() that allows to modify which are not shown as long as user hadn't modified his preferences in screen options

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_hidden_meta_boxes

Comment: Hmmm, not quite what I'm after. the screen options are also controlling the visible columns in things like the page list. this is the type of control I am after.

Comment: In case any one is looking to control visible columns only and not remove meta boxes, there is a working solution here using the default_hidden_columns filter: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/314710/160457. Note that it will only work for new users who don't already have their own custom options saved in the database. I was able to delete my own custom settings to test it on my local site (without creating a new user) and it works.